# Dynamic way to read a file in Java

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code in my reading File method:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fName);
bf = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("Worker")) {
        info  = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
        worker = new Worker(new Point(x, y);
        globalList.add(worker);
    }
    if (line.contains("Work")) {
        info  = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
        work = new Work(new Point(x, y);
        globalList.add(work);                   
    }
    if (line.contains("Bulldozer")) {
        info  = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
        bulldozer = new Bulldozer(new Point(x, y);
        globalList.add(bulldozer);                  
    }
}
```

With this piece of code I'm reading from a file that looks like this:

```
Worker 5 0
Bulldozer 7 5
Work 4 2
Work 4 8
```

I am using `BufferedReader` to do this, I am creating instances of a class in this case classes `Worker`, `Bulldozer` and `Work`, reading the word in the file(that is the name of the class) and getting the x and y position, and add that object to a list.

And this works perfectly, my problem is that this looks really hard coded and that's not a good idea, since this a school project, so do you guys have any tip to help me make this code a bit more dynamic, maybe with just on if statement?

Comment: You can break all your "Hard coded" values into a config file and read them in, or put them in a database.

Comment: Sounds like a task for reflection - you can dynamically instantiate an object of each type given their name, and pass in the appropriate `Point` parameter.

Comment: Yeah i tried to do that, but i would always get an error, i used the value of info[0], that would be the name.

Comment: You do know that any line that contains `Worker` also contains `Work`, right? Did you mean to use `else if`?

Comment: yeah im aware of that, but thats a problem easy to solve tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all three branches of your `if` do the same thing - they read two integers, prepare a point, then inject it into an object.

The only thing that varies is the first string and the class name. With reflection, you could make it universal - search the package for the class named like the string, create the `Point`, then call a single-argument constructor of the class.

Without reflection, you can still extract it by a method that takes as arguments a `String` and a `Function<Point, Object>` that serves as the factory.

The method would do this:

```
public void readIfMatches(String line, String match, Function<Point, Object> factory) {
    if (line.contains(match)) {
        String info  = line.split(" ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);
        globalList.add(factory.apply(new Point(x, y));
    }
}
```

Then you call the three iterations like this:

```
readIfMatches(line, "Bulldozer", Bulldozer::new)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, ill try that :)